# Cucumber/Capybara have_selector fails to find span added with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am experiencing a frustrating problem with what should be a very simple cucumber test. The test tries to submit a simple form without entering any form data, and expects to see an error message:

```
Given(/^a user visits the account confirmation page$/) do
  visit root_path
end

When(/^the user enters an improperly formatted email address$/) do
  click_button "START"
end

Then(/^the user should see an error message$/) do
  page.should have_selector("error")
end
```

The error message element is attached by JQuery and is given the css class 'error'.  The element in page it is attached to has the css class 'Forms-TextError'. This span is part of the base html.

```
<span id="email_error" class="Forms-TextError">
  <span class="error" for="email">Please provide your contact email</span>
</span>
```

The problem is that have_selector will not find the error span. It will not find its parent span either. One would think it would work for that case, since that span is part of the base html.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which driver do you use?

Comment: Whatever the default driver is. rack_test, I think

Comment: RackTest doesn't evaluate Javascript. You should use another driver if you want to test your application this way

Comment: Ok, I've tried specifying javascript and then selenium for this scenario. javascript blows up with a 'superclass mismatch for class Mysql2Adapter', and selenium results in the same failure I was getting before

Comment: It's strange. Please try to follow Setup and Drivers sections of [Capybara README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Success now with the selenium driver. I had altered the test since I posted the question. Restoring it to its original state and using selenium makes it work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line:

```
page.should have_selector("error")
```

This line (or css selector) is saying that the page should have an element of type "error", which is not likely to exist.

You should change the css-selector to one of the following:

```
#Find a span with class error:
page.should have_selector("span.error")

#Find any element with class error:
page.should have_selector(".error")
```

Comment: Neither of those work (I assume you mean something like 'span.error' in your first example)

Comment: Ok, now I get it. I didn't really understand how have_selector worked